# SQLite with Cygwin or standalone from the SQLite website?

Tags: sqlite, cygwin

I wish to install SQLIte. But I know nothing about SQLite database and the how to install it. I'm not sure whether to install SQLite standalone from it's website *or* install SQLite through Cygwin. I have already installed Python 2.7 on my system.

Answer (score 0):

There are [Precompiled Binaries for Windows](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) available.

[SQLite bindings](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3) come included with Python.